# Unzip only updated files

Tags: command-line, zip

Is there a way to unzip a zip file into a directory, but only do so for updates files (I mean the compressed files inside the zip)? 
I have a huge directory of files there, and only about 20% are different.

Preferably using command line, but it's optional. I use Windows XP.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify? DO you only want to unzip if the .zip has changed or do you want to unzip only the files in the .zip that have changed? Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [winzip commandline addon](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm), you can use the `-n` option:

> ### `-n`
>
> Unzip only newer files. This option updates existing files if the archived file is newer and creates new ones if they do not already exist.
>
> ```
> wzunzip -n "c:\my documents\spring2007.zip" c:\semesters\spring05
> ```
>
> This example will extract, from c:\my documents\spring2007.zip, ONLY those files that are newer than the files that currently exist in c:\semesters\spring05 OR that do not already exist in the c:\semesters\spring05 folder.

You might want to combine it with the `-o` option - "Overwrite existing files without a prompt (automatically reply "Yes" to each overwrite prompt)."

Comment: The equivalent for *nix users is : `unzip -u`

Answer (score 1):

Heres an idea for starters that someone else will need to finish:

1. Find a zip program that list the files in a compressed archived.
2. Have that list all the files and the timestamp
3. Use a scripting language (python,batch,whatever) to compare the modified time of those files with the files in the directory
4. Have the scripting language generate the arguments to add those files into the archive

Alternatively, break down your archive folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am arriving 4 years too late, but hey - better late than never.

Here is a project to unzip only modified files:
https://code.google.com/p/unzip-skip-unchanged-files/

From TFA:
"A unzip tool written in C#, which checks MD5 hash before unzipping each file. --- If the hash matches previous version, we skip the extraction of this file. --- Hashes are stored in NTFS Alternate files streams (on Linux, one should use xattr API, but this is not implemented here)"

Answer (score 0):

The opensource tool mentioned here looks abandoned, we we've built our own:

https://github.com/jitbit/unzipnew

(opensource, .NET/Win based, zero dependencies)