# Using WinZip, is there anyway to extract and overwrite just the newer files on a remote FTP server

Tags: ftp, extract, winzip

I have a zip of a pretty large website.  I FTP the zip over to the server and then unzip it and extract to the website folder but this is very slow.

Is there anyway to just extract and copy the files that are newer (compared to all files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unzip only updated files](http://superuser.com/questions/144472/unzip-only-updated-files)

Comment: @harrymc - the dup you suggest is for local files - this question is for remote FTP.

Comment: @Shevek: There are many more dups possible for FTP than for local files. Example: http://superuser.com/questions/25544/free-program-to-sync-folder-with-ftp

Comment: @harrymc - fair point, but your original dupe link was for unzip, not ftp sync :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason to upload a ZIP then decompress?

I use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) which has a built in FTP engine to compare my local web source directory to the FTP remote directory.

This highlights which files have changed and I only upload those.

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a free FTP client which also has a directory comparison feature

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) due to its advanced file and directory comparison. This is great to use if you do not have shell access to the server and cannot extract files using specified switches for "tar" or "unzip".

***When transferring files***

- Select the "Overwrite if source newer" radio button
- Select "Always use this action" if you are going to use this on a daily basis or maybe just for the current upload queue.

[image]